# SPFX is it possible to conditionally provisioning assets?

Tags: provisioning

I understand how to provision say a list with SPX asset provisioning.
Works like a charm.  BUT!
I now have a weird requirement to only create/provision a list(s) when some condition is met.
Take this contrived example:
when my spfx app (contains some webparts)

if(sitename == "FooSite"){

make List A

}
else{

DO NOT make List A

}

How in the wide world of sports can I get something like this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, but not using declarative provisioning (i.e. Feature Framework). Instead, you need to provision the list (or other objects) using code. This would generally be done in the `onInit()` method of the web part. You'd first check to see if the condition is met (e.g. site name equals "FooSite"), you'd then check to see if the resource had previously been provisioned. If the condition is met and the resource doesn't exist, then you'd provision it.

Comment: Thank you!  I figured that might be the case, as providing a mechanism to declaratively do this would be difficult I'd imagine :)

Comment: So if I add a bit to create a list in oninit of webpart...
OnInit will fire when webpart is loaded on a page, with a condition to check if list needs to be made.   The person viewing the webpart page would need perms sufficient to make the list on the site.

I guess would need to sure first person to add webpart to page would be a site owner, etc.

Am I off base?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You could add some code to check to see if the current user has the necessary permissions and, if they don't, show them a message indicating that the site owner needs to load the page to provision the list.

Comment: Thank you Rob, you have saved my bacon this week.